# Referencing embedded resources from an embedded resource

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I am using a WinForms browser control to display some content from a html file I have embedded as resource which works fine.

I want to embed some scripts and stylesheets in my application now, but can't figure out how to reference other embedded files from the html page, if at all possible.

My current solution is to load the resources and add them to the browser control's document before I display it, but this might be a bit messy if I want to use something like JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scripts and stylesheets are in the same directory tree as the HTML file, you can use relative paths (e.g. `<script src="../scripts/myFoo.js" />`).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: myFoo.js would be embedded in the executable as a resource just like the html file so there is no such thing as a relative path.

Comment: I see- you want them as embedded resources in the application.  Somehow I missed that.  In that case I think your current solution is probably reasonable, even if it is a little messy.

Comment: I am considering accepting this an an answer, since it let me to realize that I was trying too hard to be clever. What I did in the end was zip all html resources and extract that into the user's AppData directory on first run and not worry about injecting scripts or CSS into the WebBrowser control's document at all.

Comment: That seems like a completely reasonable approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the files and then extract each one to temp folder before rendering:

```
string ret = ResourceUtility.GetTempFileFromEmbeddedResource(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
    "outlook.addin.a.html", "a.html");

var bsjs = ResourceUtility.GetTempFileFromEmbeddedResource(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
    "outlook.addin.bootstrap.js.bootstrap.min.js", "bootstrap.min.js");

public static string GetTempFileFromEmbeddedResource(Assembly assembly, string resourceName, string fileName)
{
    string output;
    using (Stream s = ResourceUtility.GetEmbeddedResourceStream(assembly, resourceName))
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
        output = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return CreateLocalTempFile(output, fileName);
}
```